# Will String.fromCharCode() prevent spam?

Tags: javascript, spam

I saw the `String.fromCharCode()` method used to encode a `mailto:` address.  Is this effective against spammers (or was it historically)?

Comment: It will probably work for most of the evil crawlers around there, maybe that's enough for you.

Comment: Please be more specific...encode how?  `String.fromCharCode` takes a number and returns a string...that sounds more like unencoding to me.

Comment: There's always embedding the email in an png/jpeg image. But then you can't have a mailto, the human has to retype it.

Answer (score 2):

Most JavaScript methods that encode the e-mail address in a way that doesn't look like an e-mail address in markup will work.  Most of the crawlers that hit your page don't execute JavaScript.  They simply use RegEx looking for e-mail address patterns in the markup.

There are a handful out there that do execute JavaScript, but they are very rare.  It's very expensive (for server resources) to crawl pages and run JavaScript on them as well.  The mass spammers don't bother... for now.

Comment: However, I think it would not be very expensive to scan for the patterns of common email-obfuscating scripts (and then unescape them in the crawler language, without using a JS sandbox). Custom, self-written ones should not be very vulnerable, that's true.

Comment: @Bergi Agreed.  And for bigger sites, this goes out the window.  If the value of the target is high enough, it's easy for someone to write a crawler specifically for them.

Answer (score 0):

This copuld easily be overcome by a spammer who felt like it. I sometimes create an email address as two separate variables, then concat and print them at the same time. This should be more then enough obfuscation, I've never been spammed yet.

Another option is to use CloudFlare's free service, and use their Server Side Exclude tags to hide email addresses from known bots. They also have built-in email obfuscation as well.